# unexpected result with assignment expression

Tags: python

I wrote this code to try the assignment expression:

```
foods= list()
   while food := input("your food?:") != "q":
    foods.append(food)
else:
    print(foods)
```

but after input suchi and rice after running, the result was

```
[True, True]
```

Actually is did not expect this result. Can you explain??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order of operations. It's appending `input() != 'q'`, which is why you're getting `True`. You can change your loop to this:

```py
while (food := input("your food?:")) != "q":
```

Answer (score 3):

The `!=` operator has precedence over the `:=` operator (in fact, [*every other operator* has precedence over `:=`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)). So the conditional ends up as

```
while food := (input("your food?:") != "q"):
```

rather than

```
while (food := input("your food?:")) != "q":
```

Use the latter version instead and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is appending the result of `input("your food?:") != "q"` to the list, not your input.